# Pseudorandom function in Hive?

Tags: random, hash, hive

I'm trying to get a deterministic, pseudorandom function in Hive. I tried `checksum`, but apparently that's just SQL, not Hive. I did

`select hash(1)` gave me `1`

`select rand(1), rand(2), rand(3)` got me `0.730878191 0.731146936 0.731057369`

Is there a cryptographically secure hash in Hive? Why is `rand` not random?

Answer (score 0):

You can call Java library from Hive using `reflect()` or `java_method()` functions. For example sha256 from Apache [**DigestUtils**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html):

```
SELECT reflect('org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils', 'sha256Hex', 'message');
```

And as of Hive 1.3.0 SHA-2 family of hash functions are [already implemented as built-in functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

About rand() documentation says: 
Returns a random number (that changes from row to row) that is distributed uniformly from 0 to 1. **Specifying the seed will make sure the generated random number sequence is deterministic.** So, you will get the same random sequence. The same as in java.util.Random. And recommendation is: Use current time in seconds as a seed.

Comment: I want the result to deterministically, but pseudorandomly, depend on properties of the row. I don't understand why a pseudorandom process is returning results that are so similar for different seeds.

Comment: @Acccumulation Hive rand is based on java.util.Random, see source code: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFRand.java